# can not display list in jsp after passing from controller

Tags: hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to display the values of list in JSP using JSTL  tag. but nothing is displayed. i could not find out the problem. here is my code in JSP

```
 <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>

the length is ${fn:length(test1)}
 <c:forEach var="ex" items="${test1}">
   <c:out value="${ex.userid}" />
   <c:out value="${ex.password}" />
</c:forEach>
```

this is my controller code

```
@RequestMapping("/login.htm")
   public ModelAndView login(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception
    {  
        ModelMap modelMap = new ModelMap();
        List test=registrationDAO.getLoginInfo();
        modelMap.addAttribute("test1",test);
        return new ModelAndView("login",modelMap);
    }
```

this is my DAO code

```
     package registration;


    import java.util.List;
    import org.hibernate.Query;
    import org.hibernate.Session;
    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
    import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
    import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

    @Repository("registrationDAO")
    public class registrationDAOImpl implements registrationDAO{

        @Autowired 
        public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory()
        {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
            SessionFactory factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
            return factory;
        }
@Override
    public List<Login> getLoginInfo() {
        Session session=getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Query query = session.createQuery("from Login");
        List test = query.list();
        return test;
    }

}
```

this is my Login class

```
package registration;

import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "login")

public class Login {

    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "userid")
    private String userid;
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "role")
    private String role;

    public Login() {
    }

    public Login(String userid) {
        this.userid = userid;
    }

    public String getUserid() {
        return userid;
    }

    public void setUserid(String userid) {
        this.userid = userid;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }


}
```

this is web.xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: You should try to understand if your problem is in view layer or in controller/service/dao. Try to debug your controller, or simply log / print out test list size. Or in jsp use function length giving your test1 as parameter.

Comment: Try to avoid RAW type. Make the List generic.

Comment: When i print the size in controller it is showing 3. but when i print the length of "test1" in JSP using fn:length it is showing 0. i hope the syntax to pass "test1" in controller is correct. where things could be going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
    {  
        Map<String, Object> modelMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        List<Login> test=registrationDAO.getLoginInfo();

        modelMap.put("test1",test);

        return new ModelAndView("login",modelMap);
    }
```

Comment: I tried put function. but still the length of test1 in JSP is coming as 0. updated jsp code in my post. do you need to see any other part of the code?

Comment: Still the length in JSP is coming as 0

Answer (score 0):

problem was resolved. it was an import problem of model and view class. instead of importing import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

my controller imported it from import org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView;

now the length is being shown and data is displayed correctly